# Why is a mathematical condition not being evaluated in dynamic SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have tried the below script that checks a condition and produces a boolean result. But if I give any mathematical function it doesn't work and it doesn't display a value.

```
declare
     l_sql       varchar2(4000);
     l_condition varchar2(4000);
     ignore      pls_integer;
     l_cursor    number;
     l_names     dbms_sql.varchar2_table;     
begin
   for i in 1..2 loop     
       if i = 1 then
           l_condition := 'sysdate > to_date(''1/1/2007'',''mm/dd/yyyy'')';
       else
           l_condition := ':P1_ITEM = ' 'foo' '';
       end if;

       l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
       l_sql := 'begin wwv_flow.g_boolean := '||l_condition||'; end;';
       l_names := wwv_flow_utilities.get_binds(l_sql);
       dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor,l_sql,dbms_sql.NATIVE);

       for i in 1 .. l_names.count loop
           dbms_sql.bind_variable( l_cursor, l_names(i), v( substr(l_names(i),2) ), 32000 );
       end loop;

       ignore := dbms_sql.execute(l_cursor);
       dbms_sql.close_cursor( l_cursor );

       if wwv_flow.g_boolean then
           dbms_output.put_line(l_condition||' is true.');
       else
           dbms_output.put_line(l_condition||' is false.');
       end if;       
   end loop;
end;
```

I'm trying to evaluate using `l_condition:= (5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) OR 10`. Why isn't it working?

Comment: What is the math function your code fails on ?

Comment: can you add this `wwv_flow_utilities` ?

Comment: I simply tried an equation in l_condition:= (5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) OR 10

Comment: But there is no solution or return value ...i dont know whether there is any function calculate the value or return a value for the formula ...pls help me to do this

Comment: You have server output on, you don't see true/false, and you don't get any exception? That condition isn't valid 'or 10' isn't right. And presumably you actually have that as a string assignment, or you'd get PLS-00382 from that. (The FOO check in the question doesn't look right either but that might have been changed to hide something?)

Comment: For the above program,i getting output with specific given condition,but need to solve the mathematical value (5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) OR 10

Comment: Solve what though? You're trying to evaluate `(TRUE AND FALSE) OR 10` which doesn't make sense. What error are you getting? It works without the `OR 10` part (gets false), with it you will get PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type. Are you doing something to suppress the error stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you've said you're trying to "solve the mathematical value (5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) OR 10", but that is not a mathematical function or valid boolean logic. If you actually do the evaluation then `5 > 3` is true and `40 > 50` is false, and AND'ing those together is valid so far; but then you're trying to OR the result of that with the number 10, not another boolean expression. So you're doing:

```
(TRUE AND FALSE) OR 10
```

If you plug that into your code it throws an exception; you've shown your assignment as:

```
l_condition:= (5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) OR 10
```

which would give you a simple `PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type` from that assignment in the block. If you quoted it you'd get the same error from the dynamic SQL (removing the irrelevant binding):

```
create package wwv_flow as
  g_boolean boolean;
end wwv_flow;
/

declare
     l_sql       varchar2(4000);
     l_condition varchar2(4000);
     ignore      pls_integer;
     l_cursor    number;
     l_names     dbms_sql.varchar2_table;     
     g_boolean boolean;
begin
   for i in 1..2 loop     
       if i = 1 then
           l_condition := 'sysdate > to_date(''1/1/2007'',''mm/dd/yyyy'')';
       else
--           l_condition := ':P1_ITEM = ' 'foo' '';
           l_condition:= '(5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) OR 10';
       end if;

       l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
       l_sql := 'begin wwv_flow.g_boolean := '||l_condition||'; end;';
--       l_names := wwv_flow_utilities.get_binds(l_sql);
       dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor,l_sql,dbms_sql.NATIVE);

--       for i in 1 .. l_names.count loop
--           dbms_sql.bind_variable( l_cursor, l_names(i), v( substr(l_names(i),2) ), 32000 );
--       end loop;

       ignore := dbms_sql.execute(l_cursor);
       dbms_sql.close_cursor( l_cursor );

       if wwv_flow.g_boolean then
           dbms_output.put_line(l_condition||' is true.');
       else
           dbms_output.put_line(l_condition||' is false.');
       end if;       
   end loop;
end;
/

ORA-06550: line 1, column 52:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1199
ORA-06512: at line 20
```

If you remove the 'OR 10` part then it works:

```
declare
...
           l_condition:= '(5 > 3 AND 40 > 50)';
...
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

sysdate > to_date('1/1/2007','mm/dd/yyyy') is true.
(5 > 3 AND 40 > 50) is false.
```

So the problem isn't that your code doesn't work, it's that your condition isn't valid. If you are running this from within another block that is suppressing the exception (e.g. a `when others` exception handler), or your client or whatever is calling this is not reporting the exception, you need to find out why and fix that too.